# Cannot make retry with npm exponential-backoff

Tags: javascript

**Node**As you can see I am trying to call the same url on failure of response. Am doing anything wrong here

```
import * as request from 'request';

var url = 'https://www.abcxyz.com';

export class ServiceClass {
    public getRequest(): any {
        request.get(url, null, (error: any, meta: any, response: any) => {
            console.log("1111", response);
        })
    }

}

import { ServiceClass } from './GithubApiService';
import { backOff } from "exponential-backoff";

const service = new ServiceClass();

async function test() {
    const response = await backOff(() => service.getRequest(),
        { numOfAttempts: 3, maxDelay: 2000, retry: (e: any, attemptNumber: 1) => true })
};

test();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://www.npmjs.com/package/exponential-backoff docs your getRequest is not returning promise value, and should, so try to do this like that:

```js
export class ServiceClass {
    public getRequest(): any {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          request.get(url, null, (error: any, meta: any, response: any) => {
            if (error) return reject(error);
            resolve(response);
          });
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: How can we check if the retrials have been initiated. Coz I see that request is getting rejected with the first attempt

Comment: Put there some logic like `console.count('request');` before making request